# How to document code with variants? (JavaDoc for ifs)

Tags: java, javadoc

**tl;dr** is there JavaDoc for `if`s?

### Intro

I am writing an enterprise application for multiple customers. 99% of the code base is shared, but every now and then there is a variant like this:

```
if (user.hasModule(REPORTS)) { 
  ...conditional code... 
}
```

I would now like to document all these variants for the users. It should be clear from the documentation what happens if I turn on eg. the module `REPORTS`. I believe this documentation should be written in the JavaDoc manner - meaning it should be as close as possible to the conditional code. It could look like this:

```
/** Enables the cool report. */
if (user.hasModule(REPORTS)) { 
  ...conditional code... 
}
```

Or this:

```
@Doc(text="Enables the cool report.")
if (user.hasModule(REPORTS)) { 
  ...conditional code... 
}
```

Or perhaps this:

```
if (user.hasModule(REPORTS, "Enables the cool report.")) { 
  ...conditional code... 
}
```

The result would be basically a list of comments for each module.

```
Module    | Comments
----------+--------------------
REPORTS   | Enables the cool report.
REPORTS   | Allows exporting the reports.
IMPORT    | Allows importing the data.
```

### Question

**How to gather all the documentation comments from the code?** I am considering several approaches:

#### Source code extraction

This would require a parser to traverse the source code, find all such conditions and fetch pairs (module, comment). It would, however, have to be hooked into the compiler to avoid problems with weird formatting (newlines in the middle of a long line etc).

#### Dynamic extraction

Whenever `user.hasModule()` is invoked during the runtime it logs its actual arguments, this log is then used to build the documentation. So for example during the beta-testing the documentation is gathered and then built into the final release. The downside is clear: if a certain part of the system is not accessed, it will not be documented.

#### Bytecode extraction

To avoid the messy source code one can just reach for the compiled bytecode, analyze it with something like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org) and find all the places where `user.hasModule()` is invoked. This is the version I like the most, but got stuck
with how to figure out what is the actual value on the top of the VM stack at the moment of calling `invoke_static`. There has to be a simpler way :)

### Summary

Is there a tool for this? Am I missing a simple way to do this? Am I completely misguided in my attempts to document such conditions? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Do you want to document what happens inside the `if` for other developers? Or do you want to generate documentation for users at runtime, depending on what module is enabled? It all sounds a little strange to me.

Comment: The latter - documentation for the users.

Comment: Then Javadoc is not your tool of choice. It's for documenting the code and is not meant for being read by users. It's way to technical for that.

Comment: Also JavaDoc absolutely cannot document code structures like `ifs`, so it's not JavaDoc I am looking for - but rather something in a similar spirit.

Comment: I still don't get why you want to document a code structure for the user. He is not interested in what's happening in the code, he wants to know how the software works.

Comment: Suppose there are hundreds of these conditions throughout the code, defining in subtle ways how will the software work based on which modules are available. The user needs to understand what functionality she gets with modules X Y Z, so some kind of documentation is necessary. Rather than asking the developers to keep such documentation up-to-date in a written form I believe it would be best to leverage the ideas of JavaDoc - document locally, gather the documentation later.

Comment: I believe (1) end-user documentation shouldn't be written by developers and (2) developers should develop their code *based* on the user documentation, which is a description of what the code should do, not the other way around. You first decide what you software does, then implement it. If you already implemented it and want to document it, you already did it wrong.

Comment: Is what you need is to write a javadoc 'taglet'. Or perhaps some kind of Maven Report? All you need to do is have a start and end tag in java comments like //startsnippettag and //endsnippettag then some mechanism for parsing .java files and extracting everything between?

Comment: @Richard: I am trying to avoid parsing the source code directly. These tags could occur anywhere an `if` lives, meaning in some more complicated code structures...

Comment: If you're considering doing this at runtime then someone else has already mentioned AOP. You might also consider MBeans, or perhaps a combination of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing a concept in your code.

Your modules look a lot like security **groups**, each usage looks a lot like a **permission**.

If you were to model things this way you could concentrate the knowledge of what the usages/permission were for each module into one location. There would then be no need to scan through the code via static analysis.

The scheme below uses the Java type system to ensure you could not add an if statement for a module without first creating a new permission for that module.

A complete list of permissions and descriptions could be easily generated from this code with a little java looping through the enum values.

```
public interface User {
 public <T extends Module<T>> boolean hasPermission(Module<T> module, Permission<T> usage);
 }

public interface Permission<T extends Module<T>> {
  String describe();
}

enum Reports implements Module<Reports> {
  REPORTS
}

enum ReportsPermissions implements Permission<Reports> {
   ENABLE_COOL_REPORT("Enables the cools reports"),
   ALLOWS_EXPORTING_THE_REPORTS("Allow exports the cools reports");

   private final String description;

    ReportsPermissions(String description) {
      this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String describe() {
      return description;
     } 
  }

  enum ImportPermissions implements Permission<Import> {
    ALLOWS_IMPORTING("Allows importing the data.");
    etc
  }
```

This is most likely overkill - one simple enum without all the self typing nonsense is probably enough.

`if user.hasPermission(Permissions.Export)`

Comment: This is precisely how the module definition works now. I call it _modules_, because there also are _permissions_, and yes, the issue relates to them as well.

Comment: However, we are trying to document all the ifs - imagine there are 100 ifs that use each of the enum values!

Comment: My point is, each "if" must relate to some observable functionality. You should create a model of that functionality - at the moment the module concept is not capturing that, you need to go one step deeper.

Comment: So you'd basically have an enum of all the ifs?

Comment: In effect, presumably it will not be 1:1 as an observable feature may require branches in more than 1 location, but yes create model of what the if statements are trying to achieve and document that.

Comment: I see the point and agree that it's a clean solution. However, we are still talking about hundreds of such ifs - it would be terribly inconvenient to add such an enum in the existing code, and would add friction to developing the future code. Not sure if the correctness / clarity this adds is worth it...

Comment: I'd argue that writing a custom static analysis tool and requiring developers to stick to a codebase specific coding convention creates a lot more friction. You'd need some sort of manual process to confirm that the output of any tool that worked this way was correct.

Comment: Suppose the last parameter of `hasPermission()` is a string with the comment - you could make it optional in the transitional period and then start requiring it. The compiler would enforce the coding convention...

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the code that's executed when `user.hasModule(REPORTS)==true` into an [aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). Then document the aspect with JavaDoc.